# Search singular point of a map on ball to Euclidean Space

Tags: differential-geometry

[image]

I know the form of map $f$ told us the singular point of this map would be symmetry, but I still do not know which conditions I should to use the to solve the problem or what techniques I need for this problem. Please give me a answer for this question in details.

Answer (score 0):

We start with the differential of $f$:
$$df=\begin{pmatrix}[-1\cdot dx+z\cdot dy+y\cdot dz] & [z\cdot dx-1\cdot dy+x\cdot dz] & [y\cdot dx+x\cdot dy-1\cdot dz]\end{pmatrix}$$
Basically, that's the total derivative, expressed in differential form. Now, we restrict that to the tangent space. At a given point $(x,y,z)$, the tangent space is the subspace $x\,dx+y\,dy+z\,dz=0$ - the surface $S^2$ is a level set, so its tangent is the normal to the gradient of that function.

But then, the restriction is a bit tricky to work with in general. Let's set it aside for a moment, and see what we can do with the unrestricted version.

In matrix form, we can write that differential as
$$df = \begin{pmatrix}dx&dy&dz\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}-1&z&y\\z&-1&x\\y&x&-1\end{pmatrix}$$
Our vectors $\begin{pmatrix}dx&dy&dz\end{pmatrix}$ lie in a subspace of dimension $2$. If that derivative matrix $F'$ has full rank $3$, then any linear operators that come from restricting its domain to a dimension-2 subspace will also have full rank $2$ - so we should be able to rule out a lot that way. The determinant of $F'$ is $-1+2xyz+x^2+y^2+z^2$, which is equal to $2xyz$ on the sphere. Everywhere other than the three great circles at which the sphere intersects the coordinate planes $x=0$, $y=0$, or $z=0$ will be nonsingular.

Now, we take a closer look at those circles. Suppose $x=0$. The tangent plane is now the subspace $y\,dy+z\,dz=0$, and we can simplify our expressions with $x=0$ and $y^2+z^2=1$. If (WLOG) $z\neq 0$, we can solve to get $dz=\frac yz\,dy$, and we get
$$df=\begin{pmatrix}[-1\cdot dx + (z+\frac{y^2}{z})\cdot dy] & [z\cdot dx +(-1)\cdot dy] & [y\cdot dx + (-\frac yz)\cdot dy]\end{pmatrix}$$
That's a linear combination of two vectors $(-1,z,y)$ and $\begin{pmatrix}z+\frac{y^2}{z}&-1&-\frac yz\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac1z&-1&-\frac yz\end{pmatrix}$. The two vectors are linearly dependent, and this arbitrary point $(0,y,z)$ on the circle $x=0$ is indeed a singular point - the differential restricted to the tangent space has rank $1$.

By symmetry, the same applies to the other circles. The singular points are the union of the three circles $x=0$, $y=0$, and $z=0$. In other words, every point on the sphere with one of its coordinates zero.